# Given the position vectors of the vertices of a triangle, prove that another point is the orthocentre of the triangle.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry

The original problem is:

If a, b, c, d are the position vectors of points A, B, C, D respectively such that $$(\vec{a}-\vec{d}). (\vec{b}-\vec{c})= (\vec{b}-\vec{d}). (\vec{c}-\vec{a})= 0$$then prove that D is the orthocentre of ${\Delta}$ ABC.

How do we go  about proving that a point is the orthocentre of a triangle? I've tried expanding the dot product but I don't seem to get anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That formula states that $AD\perp BC$ (so that $D$ is on the altitude from $A$ to $BC$)
and that $AC\perp BD$ (so that $D$ is on the altitude from $B$ to $AC$).
As $D$ is on two altitudes of the triangle, it is its orthocentre.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

You don't have to expand it, just use it as it is. Equation $$(a-d)(b-c)=0$$ means that $AD$ is perpendicular to $BC$ and second equation means...